# Is it possible to DISABLE auto-reverting remote file?

Tags: revert-buffer, global-auto-revert-mode

Emacs 26.3
Linux Mint 19.3

I work with my Google drive. I want to disable auto reverting mode for remote files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

Set `auto-revert-remote-files` to `nil`. This disables auto reverting for all files with Tramp syntax.

If you want to disable auto reverting of remote files in a mounted directory, or in a sync directory, add that directory name to `auto-revert-notify-exclude-dir-regexp`.

Comment: Somehow I missed `auto-revert-remote-files` :)  I did see `auto-revert-notify-exclude-dir-regexp` but from the name that seemed like it should only affect reverts driven by filesystem notification systems, and therefore not affect auto-revert polling?

Comment: That's true, `auto-revert-notify-exclude-dir-regexp` disables file notifications. But you can combine it with `auto-revert-avoid-polling`. Both set proper, you'll get only file notifications for local file systems, and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

You could use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `global-auto-revert-ignore-buffer` with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `find-file-hook`

```el
(defun my-inhibit-remote-auto-revert ()
  "Used in `find-file-hook'."
  (when (file-remote-p buffer-file-name)
    (setq global-auto-revert-ignore-buffer t)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-inhibit-remote-auto-revert)
```

Comment: I'll leave this answer here in case the approach helps someone for a different scenario, but the answer by @MichaelAlbinus is unquestionably the way to go for this question.